# SQL extract based on string expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've two tables. one is product master code and 2nd one product details. I've the master code like R*0* OR K*3* and some data like R*** and ***K.
I've the corresponding code stored in master table like:

```
R*0*: R100,R200,R300...
K*3*: K030,KA31
```

which means * should be replaced by the corresponding codes from the master table.

I want to extract the corresponding product codes from the master table in SQL query. Please help me out.
table1:

[image]

table2:

[image]

output table should be:

[image]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` operator as below:

```
select distinct t1.product_id, t2.product_code
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 
   on t2.product_code like replace(t1.code, '*', '%')
```

Please find the db<>fiddle [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a606c55117f878e830d72fbd98c91b4).